# Is there anyway for passing props from drawer to nested scene in RNRF?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Version
 -- react-native-router-flux: v4.0.0-beta.31
 -- react-native: v0.55.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Vdy.png)
Actually, I want to passing props("Recent_Measurement") from drawer(in this case, "main_tab") to its nested scence ("measure_tab").
However, whenever I try to pass props to the nested scene, it cannot recognize.

For reference, below figure is about my router-flux structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZmVz.png)